# Solaris + equivalent to the linux screen command 

Tags: linux

---

is there a solaris equivalent to the linux screen command?

Example how to use the screen command  in Linux

```
  example for linux :  screen -D -m   ./run_some_script.pl 


  example for Solaris : ?
```

Man page for screen command for Linux: 
http://www.oreillynet.com/linux/cmd/cmd.csp?path=s/screen

Comment: What do you mean?  Is GNU Screen not installed?  If it doesn't, then find a package, or download the source and install it.  http://www.gnu.org/s/screen/

Comment: @Zoredache see my update

Comment: Your update didn't really change anything.  Screen is a piece of software, it can be install onto Solaris.

Comment: @Zoredache The Solaris system belong to the customer ( BANK company) and he didn’t want to make on the Solaris system any installation changes , so I only ask if we can find similar command for screen that already exist in Solaris - thx for your advice this is critical subject

Comment: Perhaps you can update your question with details about the specific version of Solaris that was Installed?  I have almost zero familiarity, but I would expect there are differences in what packages are installed by default.  Knowing what version is install may help someone else tell you want exactly is available, or at least what it would take to install screen or an alternative.

Comment: @Diana: Assuming the Solaris system has a C compiler, you should be able to build GNU screen from source and install it under your own home directory.  I would think that the customer would be less likely to object to that than to installing software as root.

Comment: The "linux" screen command was originally written by Oliver Laumann on BSD and SunOS based system. Sorry to disappoint... Reference [Posting to net.sources](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/net.sources/5V9QWdIynTY)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a substitute for screen, if you want to be able to run the process in the background without having it shutdown when you exit the server (or drop your connection), then there are few options:

- Run the process in a subshell like so:

  **(myprog -opts &)**
- Disown the process (if you have bash or zsh) after putting it in the background:

  **myprog -opts & ; disown**
- Run the script with nohup:

  **nohup ./myprog 2>&1 &**

In most of the above cases, the process is detached from the user and put under "init". That meant you can safely exit without the process getting shutdown (otherwise, exiting the shell will send a SIGHUP to the program, which will shut it down).

However, you will not be able to reattach to that process. So for whatever program you run using the above options, you'll need to write standard output to file like so (for example, this):

```
nohup ./myprog  2>&1>myprog.log &
```

And then monitor that file.

Comment: where to put the myprog in the syntax nohup find / 2>&1>found.log &

Comment: I updated the last example to make it more clearer.

Answer (score 7):

GNU screen is not a `linux` tool, it is a [GNU](http://www.gnu.org/) tool, that is commonly included on Linux, but it is also commonly found on BSD, OSX, and *nix.  It should be trivial to install it onto Solaris, and there is probably a package available already.

An alternative to GNU screen is called [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).  Though I believe this is less common.

Comment: Just ran this on a Solaris 10 box: `screen -v`, output: _Screen version 4.00.02 (FAU) 5-Dec-03_

Comment: screen isn't standard on Solaris 10, but is easy to build, see https://jamalahmed.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/install-screen-on-solaris-10/, note my comments at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you must install screen for Solaris you can get it from [OpenCSW](http://www.opencsw.org/packages/screen/).